# When I apply dir=rtl on the html the page disapears - in Mobile only

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have some strange error with dir="rtl"

I have this page: 
http://facebook-emoticons.he.downloadastro.com/tools/

But when I open it in mobile, or in Chrome Mobile Emulator the content displayed for a second and then moved away from screen.

If I remove dir="rtl" from the html it works ok... but then other elements are incorrect on the page.

I cannot find the css error that creates this. In desctop all of it works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page on mobile is pretty wide, if you scroll max to right you will see the content.

```
<span id="swf_tmp"></span>
```

This element is causing the problem, especially his `left:-9999px` part.

Edit: maybe since your dir is right to left, set it to `right:-9999px` instead?

Comment: I was looking for this rough element for a few hours now... thank you!

Comment: If the problem was flipping a CSS definition from left:xxx to right:xxx, you can look into using CSSJanus to flip the definitions in your CSS automatically (left: xxx turns into right: xxx, etc) https://github.com/cssjanus